# UITableView cell not deleting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Basically I have an app where you can swipe a tablecell off the screen and it "deletes" the cell. My delete method is called by this: (this happens when the cell reaches a certain point on the phone)

```
    [tableCellTrash addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[numbers indexOfObject:[aPanGestureRecognizer view]] inSection:0]];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [numbers objectAtIndex:[numbers indexOfObject:[aPanGestureRecognizer view]]];
        [self deleteCell: cell];
```

This is the delete cell method

```
-(void)deleteCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell{


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
   [numbers removeObject:cell];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tableCellTrash withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [tableCellTrash removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];


    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong, the cell doesn't delete. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `numbers` an array of cells or is that your data source?  Also, are you sure that your tableCellTrash contains the proper index paths?

Comment: In deleteRowsAtIndexPaths the tableCellTrash needs to be an NSArray of NSIndexPaths that specify the section and row to delete? Where is tableCellTrash setup and what is in it?

Comment: Have you verified that `deleteCell:` is called the the correct index row?

Answer (score 0):

tableviews have a delegate method to handle the event for delete:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the predefined editing thing iOS provides. My cell literally swipes off the screen, so I have to write a custom detector/method.